# In google app engine, how to iterate through form fields (python, wsgiref.handlers)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgiref

Using python and wsgiref.handlers, I can get a single variable from a form with self.handler.request.get(var_name), but how do I iterate through all form variables, be they from GET and POST? Is it something like this?

for field in self.handler.request.fields:
    value = self.handler.request.get(field)

Again, it should include both fields included in the POST and fields from the query string, as in a GET request.

Thanks in advance folks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_arguments

```
for field in self.request.arguments():
  value = self.request.get(field)
```

Answer (score 0):

A modification of Drew's answer worked great for me:

```
params = {}
for field in self.request.arguments():
  params[field] = self.request.get(field)
```

Comment: If you're just constructing a dict out of them, you could just refer to `self.request.arguments` directly, which is already a dict.

Comment: Good to know, @Nick Johnson. I think I went down this path because the docs say: Returns a `list` of the names of query (URL) or POST data arguments.